# How to connect to specific store view through Magento2 REST API

Tags: magento2, api, multistore, store-view

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812859/use-magento-rest-api-with-multi-store-view) on the main Stack Overflow site indicating how to connect to a specific store view in the Magento 1 REST API.

I'm curious how to do this with the Magento2 API. Looking at [the documentation generated by swagger](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#resource_catalogProductRepositoryV1) I don't see anything about how to specify a store view in the **catalogProductRepositoryV1** section.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send something like this:

```
[POST] /rest/6/V1/guest-carts/75fc406b9aadbad6fe1b9a2df9881acd/items
```

Where "6" is the storeId

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm most interested in an example using a swagger generated client. This is a start for sure.